# Referencing several DLLs from my application .NET

Tags: .net, reference

I have developed several dlls and they are all lying in a directory. 
Now I am creating a new program (Unit Test Project) which would require to load these dlls and through reflection do certain things.

My query is what is the best way to reference these DLLs in my new program.
1) Should I create a new folder within the \Debug and copy paste all the dlls within them and set the program to read from the path.
2) Should I create a new folder within the solution directory (outside \bin) and paste all those dlls there and set the program to read from that path.

I am quite novice at this stuff. Can you please give me the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you talking about a plugin system ? if yes, take a look at MEF... it does exactly what you seems to want. Especially, one of the feature is to autoanalyse a folder to get all implementations of a custom interface.

Comment: @steve: It is a Unit Test project which will contain test methods to test the dlls. what is this MEF? I would like to take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: take a look at [Managed Extensibility Framework - Using catalog page](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Catalogs). In very few words, MEF will allow you to dynamically discover types that implement a specific interface.

Answer (score 1):

In the solution explorer in your program:
right click on **References** .. then choose **Add Reference** .. go for the **Browse** tab .. and select your DLLs .. 
Rebuild your program and you are all set .. you can use them by adding them in the references on the top of each document you want to use these DLLs at ..  for example:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am aware of this method. Is this the best way? Because going ahead I will have about 100 Dlls and this program will need to reference these 100 DLLs. Was wondering if that was a good idea!!!

Comment: a good question would be .. are you gonna use all the functions of these dlls? or just some functions of each? in that case .. if u have the code of the classes .. append the classes that u need only .. if u don't have the code .. here you have to think it over .. because when u load your program .. the dlls will be loaded into memory so if u r using only few functions .. then u r wasting precious resources! DLLs could make performance issues as much as they could make your work easier .. so you have to use them wisely ..

Comment: btw .. it don't believe it matters how you attach the dlls to your program as they will end up in the same place and are gonna be used in the very same way when running your program .. only thing that matters is how much of each dll are u using! Moreover, the way i've mentioned in my answer is the official way by visual studio .. so wouldn't consider any other way ;)